# Geometry: formula for 2D perspective transformation

Tags: computational-geometry

Is there a way of describing an `perspective transformation` for one point in the 2dimenstion world?

I know you can write translation for one point for instance as: $(x*a,y*b) = (x',y')$ where $a$ describes the translation in the $X$ dimension and $b$ for the $Y$ direction.

I know that perspective transformation makes not really sense for one point, but never the less is there a way? Preferable in this one line writing styl like for the translation above.

Please note that this is required for image transformation on a 2D world, therefore there is no $z$ dimension.

One example could be this transformation:

[image]
[image]